# No events fire when I populate ComboBox programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, events, combobox

To make it as simple as possible: ComboBox1 is bound to an empty list (in Form1 load event handler), and there is an event handler associated with ComboBox1:

```
private void CB1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Event fired");
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     CB1.DataSource = list1;
     CB1.ValueMember = "Name";
     CB1.DisplayMember = "Name";
}
```

The form is loaded, CB1.SelectedIndex = -1, CB1.Text = "", CB1.Items.Count = 0

When I click on Button1, list1 is populated. Now the situation is as follows:
CB1.SelectedIndex = 0, CB1.Text = "Some Text", CB1.Items.Count =196

BUT, the event didn't fire, although SelectedIndex changed from -1 to 0, and I didn't get MessageBox.Show("Event fired"). However, when the user selects some item from the list, the event fires. Also, there is another button that clears list1, and consequently CB1.Items. When this button is pressed, the event also fires (SelectedIndex changes from X to -1).

I've tried to use other events, such as SelectedValueChanged, TextChanged, SelectionChangeCommitted, with no success.

Although there is a simple brute force workaround for this problem, I still do not understand why the problem appears in the first place, and thus cannot anticipate similar situations. That's why I would be grateful if somebody explained to me why no events are firing in the situation I described.

Comment: you could just call it yourself with your own event args.

Comment: Did you ever actually assign the event? `CB1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(CB1_SelectedIndexChanged)`

Comment: @Joel: I've made that mistake, and been left scratching my head for a few minutes.

Comment: Aren't event handlers typically `protected`? And I think there is a more specific `EventArgs` you should be using.

Comment: @Yuck event handlers are typically private, at least Visual Studio creates private methods. Also SelectedIndexChanged event uses EventArgs.

Comment: I think you should clearify list1 in the coding as well. is it List<T>?

Comment: Show us the full code. Not clear to me where do you change the _SelectedIndex_. What is _Button1_?

Comment: @JacobSeleznev as I understand him he wants to fire the selectedindexchanged event by button click event. I mean the event should be fired when the selected index is changed by buttong click event using combobox1.SelectedIndex = 1;

Comment: @JoelEtherton Good point, although the post said : **when the user selects some item from the list, the event fires.** It won't fire if not assigned.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: I call this "Is it plugged in" Syndrome. I'm frequently guilty of complaining that something doesn't work when it isn't properly plugged in. Whether it's code or a toaster.

Comment: @kashif It works as he described, so I want to see the full code, hoping that we'll find the problem.

Comment: @JacobSeleznev what about my answer. does it work according to his necessity?? i think it does

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't reply earlier: I'm using Visual studio 2010,and the event handler was assigned automatically: this.CB1.SelectedValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.CB1_SelectedIndexChanged);

Answer (score 1):

My comment got enough attention, so it seemed appropriate that I should put this as a potential answer. You should make sure that you've actually assigned the event to the method either through a delegate or in the designer with the properties of the combobox itself.

```
// Somewhere in the form load or init events
CB1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(CB1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Comment: @kashif: Unless you're fine tuning some very touchy event sequencing that should be perfectly fine. There may be times when you want to interrupt an action at the user change event `SelectedIndexChanged` before the commit occurs (validation, confirmation, modification?), but in most cases they should behave equivalently.

Comment: I think this will not solve his problem. because i want the call the selectedindexchanged event when the index of combobox1 is changed by button.Click event

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted);
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
        comboBox1.DataSource = list;
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
    private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1;

    }
}
```